# How to add delta to python datetime.time?

Tags: python, datetime, time, timedelta

From:

http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects

> A timedelta object represents a duration, the difference between two
>   dates or times.

So why i get error with this:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time
>>> datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=12)
datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 17, 6, 24, 9, 635862)
>>> datetime.now().date() + timedelta(hours=12)
datetime.date(2012, 9, 16)

>>> datetime.now().time() + timedelta(hours=12)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

`datetime.time` objects [do not support addition](https://bugs.python.org/issue1487389#msg54803) with `datetime.timedelta`s.

There is one natural definition though, clock arithmetic.
You could compute it like this:

```
import datetime as dt
now = dt.datetime.now()
delta = dt.timedelta(hours = 12)
t = now.time()
print(t)
# 12:39:11.039864

print((dt.datetime.combine(dt.date(1,1,1),t) + delta).time())
# 00:39:11.039864
```

`dt.datetime.combine(...)` lifts the datetime.time `t` to a `datetime.datetime` object, the delta is then added, and the result is dropped back down to a `datetime.time` object.

Comment: It's a lot of work. I only want to calculate a time shift, python :).
however it's solution, thanks.

Comment: One thing to note here is that if `t` is smaller than `delta`, then, you will end up with `dt.date(1,1,0)`, which is an `OverflowError: date value out of range
`. One way to approach this is to increase values in `dt.date(...)`. But this is still an issue one has to be careful with.

Comment: this is an old post, what was the Python version back then? Probably 2. I'm using Python 3 and having the same issue. The really disappointing fact is that I tried it without that whole workaround on the console and it works perfectly, then put it in my code and it completely fails. This is really very very sad. Anyway the stated workaround works.

Answer (score 19):

All the solutions above are too complicated, OP had already shown that we can do calculation between `datetime.datetime` and `datetime.timedelta`, so why not just do:

`(datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=12)).time()`

Comment: your way shows a datetime.datetime object. he has a datetime.time object

Comment: This gives a different result: `datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 17, 6, 24, 9, 635862)` instead of `datetime.date(2012, 9, 16, 12)`

Comment: @jonrios the calculation inside the parenthesis gives a `datetime.datetime` object, but then `.time()` will output a `datetime.time` object

Answer (score 5):

Here is a function that adds a `timedelta` to a `time`:

```
def time_plus(time, timedelta):
    start = datetime.datetime(
        2000, 1, 1,
        hour=time.hour, minute=time.minute, second=time.second)
    end = start + timedelta
    return end.time()
```

This will provide the expected result so long as you don't add times in a way that crosses a midnight boundary.

Answer (score 3):

How would this work? `datetime.datetime.now().time()` returns only hours, minutes, seconds and so on, there is no date information what `.time()` returns, only time.

Then, what should `18:00:00 + 8 hours` return?
There's not answer to that question, and that's why you can't add a time and a timedelta.

In other words:

```
18:28:44, Sep. 16, 2012 + 8 hours #makes sense: it's 2:28:44, Sep. 17, 2012
18:28:44 + 8 hours # Doesn't make sense.
```

Comment: While your general point is correct, 6pm + 5 hours = 11pm, so that is a bad example, and `.time()` doesn't return a timestamp -- a timestamp often includes enough information to derive a date, a `datetime.time` object does not.

Comment: @agf, yes, I was editing my post actually : ). I'll also change the use of timestamp!

Comment: Ok, i understand explanation i'm gonna used to it. call me a stupid, but in my reasoning adding hours to only date should raise exception in any of both:)
however it's not compact in this form.
I think adding time to time within a one day (24hours) could be possible. How can i achieve that in current state, like add 2h33m to now()?

Comment: @xliiv unubtu's answer will give you this : )

Answer (score 1):

I see a different approach in one of the python's forum, hope this might be helpful to others if the accepted answer is not working, I see the newer python version might not work with accepted answer.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time

d = datetime(2021, 1, 1, 7, 0)
new_date = d + timedelta(hours=7)

print(d)

#2021-01-01 07:00:00

#To print only time

print((d + timedelta(hours=7)).time())
```

credits: https://python-forum.io/thread-32268.html

Answer (score 0):

A datetime.time object can be split into separate integer components that you can add to. 
No need for timedelta eg:

```
from datetime import datetime, time
    time_now = datetime.now().time()
    twelve_hours_time =  time(time_now.hour + 12, time_now.minute)
```

Comment: This would risk pushing the hour component >23 or the minute >59 and then you'll get a `ValueError`. It's easiest to just use datetime instead of time when doing addition. I've had use cases where I just made a dummy `datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, hour, minute)` do the timedelta addition and then convert to time.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta, time    
result = datetime.combine(date.today(), test_time) + timedelta(minutes=int(gap))
print(result.time())
```

Note:minutes should be int;

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow. Please provide a description of how your answer solves the problem, provide references where appropriate and explain how your solution is different from the other answers already provided.