# Date format conversion in python

Tags: python, matlab, date

Would someone know how to convert this matlab code into python ?

```
for i=1:100
    RefTime = datenum('01-Jan-1900 00:00:00');
    MyTime=97847+i;
    t0=addtodate(RefTime,double(MyTime), 'hour');
    date(i)=datestr(t0,'yyyymmddHH');
end
```

I am trying here to convert an hourly numerical date format (MyTime) which reference point (e.g. origin) is 01-Jan-1900 at 00:00  to a YYYYMMDDHH format.

Comment: You can check this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448592/how-to-add-delta-to-python-datetime-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
import datetime
RefTime = datetime.datetime(1900,1,1,0,0,0)
OneHour = datetime.timedelta(0,3600)

date = []

for i in range(100):
    #python loop starts at 0, so add 1 to your magic number below
    MyTime = 97847 + 1 + i
    t0 = RefTime + OneHour * MyTime
    date.append(t0.strftime("%Y%m%d%H"))

#now 'date' is a list with 100 strings like "1911030200", etc.
```

Comment: Thanks, it does the job!