# how to add a const time delta to an index column in python pandas?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

i have a quick question regarding the timestamps in python pandas

```
                   date       sometime
   time
03:10:22.227138  20140210  03:10:22.227138
03:10:22.029889  20140211  03:10:22.029889
03:10:22.030458  20140312  03:10:22.030458
```

How can i add 2 minutes to all the items in the index. i.e., time column?

any quick and neat way to do this?

thanks!

Comment: a quick hack is found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448592/how-to-add-delta-to-python-datetime-time

Answer (score 2):

First answer(wrong) Use datetime.replace():

```
df["time"] = df["time"].apply(lambda x: x.replace(minute=x.minute+2))
```

This is wrong because the replace function only takes numbers from 0 to 59 as args for minutes.

Edit as the comment suggested:

```
df["time"] = df["time"].apply(lambda x: x + timedelta(minutes=2))
```

Comment: what happens if minute originally equals 58 or 59?

Comment: also, there's no reason to use apply in this case.

Comment: Yes, one could also do a direct assignment, ie
df.time = df.time + timedelta(minutes=2). Spot on about the first comment.

Comment: yeah, i was trying that, and it's annoying if it's just a time field. i think you need to convert it to a datetime first, add the timedelta, and then bring it back down...

Comment: Right. So then here is the somewhat convoluted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656297/python-time-timedelta-equivalent

Comment: timedelta is from the datetime lib I think: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects