# Python 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'time' error

Tags: python, datetime

When I run my py script I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "report_monitor.py", line 17, in <module>
timedelta(hours=7).time())
AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'time'
```

The code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import MySQLdb
import datetime 
from datetime import timedelta

db =      
MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","password","DB")
cursor = db.cursor() 
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM reportPref WHERE lastDate LIKE '2015-11-    
18%'")
records = cursor.fetchall()
for record in records:
rec = record[14]     #index 14 is a datetime object.  there is no problem here.
schedLogTime =  
(datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date(1,1,1),rec.time()) -
timedelta(hours=7).time()) 

print schedLogTime
db.close()
```

What am I missing?  This is driving me bonkers...!

Comment: Why were you trying to call the `time` method of a `timedelta` object? There's no such method.

Comment: @user2357112 Then my syntax must be wrong because I attempted to pull the syntax directly from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448592/how-to-add-delta-to-python-datetime-time but I've as of yet been unable to make my version work.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check your parentheses.

Comment: @user2357112 I have been.

Comment: why are you initiating a `timedelta` object then trying to subtract it.

Comment: @RNar I'm trying to do clock arithmetic and subtract 7 hours from a datetime time object.

Comment: then initialize a `datatime` object, not a `timedelta`. or dont call `.time()` on the `timedelta`

Answer (score 1):

Python is trying to do this:

```
timedelta(hours=7).time()
```

...which is invalid because as the error indicates, there's no such thing as a `time` method on a `timedelta` object. What you probably meant to do was:

```
(datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date(1,1,1),rec.time()) -
 timedelta(hours=7)).time()
```

...which will first subtract a `timedelta` from the `datetime`, then get the `time` of the resulting `datetime` object. (Note the move of the close parenthesis compared to your code.)

Comment: this code returns  schedLogTime = (datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date(1,1,1),rec.time()) - datetime.timedelta(hours=6)).time()
OverflowError: date value out of range

Comment: What if you change it to `datetime.date(1900,1,1)`?

Comment: Wow...that seems to be working.  What does changing the 1900 do?

Comment: @Dimpermanence The lowest year that can be represented in a datetime is 1 (see [the `datetime` docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html)). You're starting there and then attempting to subtract time from it, resulting in Python trying to build a `datetime` for year 0, which is invalid.

Comment: So this isn't performing like a "since current epoch" calculation or something like that?

Comment: @Dimpermanence `date` and `datetime` objects work on actual calendar years. Effectively, their epoch is midnight January 1, 1AD.

Comment: Subtle.  It is working.  Thanks for untangling me.  I vow to get better at this.  I always do, except I'm working with a bunch of DBs that have different timestamps so that clock arithmetic is meticulous and hairy for me as a bit of a noob.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the obvious, that timedelta objects don't have that method, `timedelta` isn't a time, it's a vector. It gives you *differences* in time. That's why it's time*delta* (delta meaning something akin to 'change in').

It makes no sense to say "what time is a 1 hour duration"

If you want to subtract 7 hours, just do:

```
timedeltaobj = datetime.timedelta(hours=7)
var = datetimeobj - timedeltaobj
```

Here's a handy little chart from the [datetime module docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

[image]

Glibud hit the nail on the head in terms of what you were probably trying to do.

Comment: Is there a better way to do clock arithmetic with a datetime time object?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. It's pretty easy once you get the hang of it... I actually use it all the time. It's also awesome because you can actually use dates as iterators, it handles leap years and such things automatically, etc.. Just take a look at the chart I put into my answer. You were trying to call `.time()` on a `timedelta` object, but I think glibud is right in that what you really wanted was to call `.time()` on a `datetime` object.

Comment: For me your code returns: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.timedelta'

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write `datetimeobj - timedeltaobj`. [That should work.](https://repl.it/B1Tg/1)