# Subtracting 1 second from time in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to `Python`. I would like to subtract *1 second* from a time. I tried the code below:

```
inp_time = "15:30:40.740"
out_time = datetime.time(int(inp_time[:2]), int(inp_time[3:5]),   int(inp_time[6:8]), int(inp_time[-3:]))
x=1
from_time = datetime.time(out_time) - datetime.timedelta(seconds=x)
```

I get error:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type datetime.time).
```

Comment: Use datetime.datetime.time

Comment: Change `datetime.time(out_time)` to just `out_time`, then see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448592/how-to-add-delta-to-python-datetime-time) for your next problem.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working now!