# convert float to hours and minutes in pandas/numpy

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, numpy

I have several columns in a pd.DataFrame in which decimal separates hours and minutes (e.g., 3.15 = 3 hours, 15 minutes). Is there a quick way to convert this so that the data are recognized as h.m ? The pandas Time Series documentation doesn't seem to apply to my case. I don't have or want to attach any dates.

I tried:

```
# create df
hour_min = pd.DataFrame({'a': [4.5, 2.3, 3.17],
             'b': [2.12, 1.13, 9.13],
             'c': [8.23, 9.14, 7.45]})
# convert to hours   
hour_min.astype('timedelta64[h]')
```

which gives

```
         a        b        c
0 04:00:00 02:00:00 08:00:00
1 02:00:00 01:00:00 09:00:00
2 03:00:00 09:00:00 07:00:00
```

but I want

```
    a     b     c
0 04:50 02:12 08:23
1 02:30 01:13 09:14
2 03:17 09:13 07:45
```

I also need the following type of result from adding/subtracting column values 1.32 + 1.32 = 3.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to use `pd.to_timedelta` in a function and `applymap` it to get the math you want. Looks something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import math


def to_t_delt(number):
    return pd.to_timedelta(f'{math.floor(number)}hours {(number - math.floor(number)) * 100}min')


hour_min = pd.DataFrame({'a': [4.5, 2.3, 3.17],
                         'b': [2.12, 1.13, 9.13],
                         'c': [8.23, 9.14, 7.45]})

hour_min = hour_min.applymap(to_t_delt)
print(hour_min)
print()
print(hour_min['a'] + hour_min['b'])
```

and yields this result:

```
         a        b        c
0 04:50:00 02:12:00 08:23:00
1 02:30:00 01:13:00 09:14:00
2 03:17:00 09:13:00 07:45:00

0   07:02:00
1   03:43:00
2   12:30:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: [Time Deltas Usage](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html) and [pandas.to_timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) API from the docs

Comment: looks great. I'm having trouble accepting answer from the app. Will do from pc in the morning. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure there should be a more efficient solution, but since no one answered yet, here is a *hacky* workaround:

```
import pandas as pd

hour_min = pd.DataFrame({'a': [4.5, 2.3, 3.17],
             'b': [2.12, 1.13, 9.13],
             'c': [8.23, 9.14, 7.45]})

def convert(number):
    hour = ('%.2f' % number).split(sep='.')[0]
    minute = ('%.2f' % number).split(sep='.')[1]
    return pd.to_datetime(hour+":"+minute, format='%H:%M')
```

Then you just need to use `applymap()`:

```
>>> hour_min = hour_min.applymap(convert)
>>> hour_min
                    a                   b                   c
0 1900-01-01 04:50:00 1900-01-01 02:12:00 1900-01-01 08:23:00
1 1900-01-01 02:30:00 1900-01-01 01:13:00 1900-01-01 09:14:00
2 1900-01-01 03:17:00 1900-01-01 09:13:00 1900-01-01 07:45:00
```

You can show the time only with:

```
>>> for i in hour_min:
    hour_min[i] = hour_min[i].dt.time    

>>> hour_min
          a         b         c
0  04:50:00  02:12:00  08:23:00
1  02:30:00  01:13:00  09:14:00
2  03:17:00  09:13:00  07:45:00
```

Comment: You beat me to the punch, but there is one thing - you should use `('%.2f' % number).split(sep='.')` instead to allow 4.5 to map to 4:50 :)

Comment: @Kevin When I do this, I get the long format output. e.g. :

        '         a                
0    1900-01-01 04:50:00

Comment: @Andrew You can convert them to show only time, but then the type won't be datetime, instead it will be object, let me edit my answer.

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar will I still be able to perform addition and subtraction, such that .34 + .33 = 1.07 (or :34 + :33 = 1:07)?

Comment: @Andrew I'm not used to this operations, so I can't answer you for sure, sorry, but I'm afraid it's not that easy, timestamps addition is always tricky, you'd have to use timedelta, you can read more about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448592/how-to-add-delta-to-python-datetime-time
" I still be able (...)" - You couldn't even do additions like that with the first conversion, because as I said, it's tricky.