# Adding time in timefield

Tags: python, django

I have a model which contains the following field

```
time_start = models.TimeField(u"Start Time", blank=False)
```

I want to add 1hr in start time and save it in a list

Here is what I have tried

```
import datetime as dt
start_time = Timeslot.objects.get(pk=1)
start = start_time.time_start
print(start)
a = (start+dt.timedelta(hours=1)).time()
print(a)
li = []
li.append(a)
```

but I am getting error

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

Comment: maybe will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448592/how-to-add-delta-to-python-datetime-time

Comment: @zimdero this is for adding hours in current time but I want to add1hr in a time which is stored in my database

Comment: @AakashPatel: but imagine that `start` is `23:45`, and you add one hour, then what should the time be?

Comment: Setting timezone in settings file is the best solution for this kind of things. You can store combined datetime field after that.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: It sholud be 00:45

Comment: @DenizKaplan: in my settings.py TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'  but I am still getting the same error

Comment: @AakashPatel: yes, but you can then use a `DateTimeField`. Storing time separately is kind of tricky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Replacing the `hour` parameter

Since a `time` object has a range from `00:00` to `23:59`. In case you add one hour, it can thus get out of range, and hence it is no longer a `time` object.

We can however implement this with **wraparound** (this means that for example `23:59` and two minutes is `00:01`) ourselves, like:

```
a = start.replace(hour=(start.hour+1) % 24)
```

We here thus replace the `hour`s of the `start` (we are not replacing it on the `start` object, but create a copy) with `(start.hour + 1) % 24`. The modulo `24` is necessary to make perform the wraparound.

## Storing a timestamp in a `DateTimeField`

The above is however *not* a nice way to do this: typically time depends on the timezone (location) and the specific date (for example *daylight saving time*, some countries have changed the timezone, etc.).

Therfore I advice you to use a `DateTimeField` instead of a `TimeField`. For example in october 28, 2018 some parts of the world enter daylight saving time, and that means that if you add one hour, the clock can in some cases, still display the same numbers. With a `TimeField`, this context is lost: we will change the numbers of the clock, regardless what the time is, and what the specific laws of the culture of the user are saying.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `combine` method for this.

```
(dt.datetime.combine(dt.date(1,1,1), start) + dt.timedelta(hours=1)).time()
```

This code will return datetime.time object as you needed.