# Django, Python unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.timedelta'

Tags: python, django

I'm creating an appointment application in Django where

`the end time of the appointment = the start_time + 30 min`

but I get this error I try a few solutions in stackoverflow, but nothing work for me

this is my forms.py

```
class AppointmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    doctor = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter(type_of_user=TypeOfUser.DOCTOR))
    date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}), input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)
    start_time = forms.TimeField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'time'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = ('doctor', 'date', 'start_time',)
```

and this is the views.py

```
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime as dt

@login_required
def create_appointement(request):
    user = User()
    if request.user.is_patient(): 
        form_appointement = AppointmentForm(request.POST or None)
        if request.method=='POST':
            form_appointement = AppointmentForm(request.POST or None)
            if form_appointement.is_valid():
                form_app = form_appointement.save(commit=False)
                form_app.user_ho_add = request.user
                form_app.end_time = form_app.start_time + dt.timedelta(minutes=30) ### 
                form_app.save()
                messages.success(request, 'appointment added')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Error')
        return render(request,'appointement/add_appointement1.html',{'form':form_appointement})
```

- Update -

my models.py

```
def defaultTitle():
    id=''
    try:
        id = str(Appointment.objects.order_by('-id').first().id + 1)
    except:
        id = '1'
    return 'patient ' + id

class Appointment(models.Model):
    user_ho_add = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_ho_add_appointment')
    patient = models.CharField(null=True,max_length = 200, default=defaultTitle)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='doctor_app')
    date = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False, default=timezone.now) 
    start_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=timezone.now)
    end_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=timezone.now)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add delta to python datetime.time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448592/how-to-add-delta-to-python-datetime-time)

Comment: so sorry i try evry thing in this answer but nothing work

Comment: post your models.py

Comment: i update the question

Comment: @houhou 1st thing you can't add time into the python time object. So try a different approach.

Comment: if there is any idea or a hit that will be awesome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is on line

`form_app.end_time = form_app.start_time + dt.timedelta(minutes=30)`

You are trying to add the time in datetime.time instance instead of datetime.datetime instance.

As per your question we can't directly update time but we can do it as

```
.
.
start_time = form_app.start_time
future_time = dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, start_time.hour, start_time.minute, start_time.second, start_time.microsecond) + timedelta(minutes=30)
form_app.end_time = dt.time(future_time.hour, future_time.minute, future_time.second, future_time.microsecond)
.
.
```