# How to add/subract operation between two different times using timedelta?

Tags: python, timedelta

So i'm trying know in what time of day the man will end running. When in last line of code, trying to use  an operator **addition** this error is popping out. What i'm doing wrong?

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.timedelta'

```
import datetime
# first run, 1 mile

pace_minutes1 = 8
pace_seconds1 = 15
distance = 1  #1 mile
b = ((pace_minutes1 * 60) + pace_seconds1) * distance
print(b)

# second run, 3 mile
pace_minutes2 = 7
pace_seconds2 = 12
distance = 3  # 3 miles
a = ((pace_minutes2 * 60) + pace_seconds2) * distance
print(a)

# third run, 1 mile run
pace_minutes3 = 8
pace_seconds3 = 15
distance = 1 # 1 mile
c = ((pace_minutes3 * 60) + pace_seconds3) * distance
print(c)

x = (a + b + c)
print(x, "seconds")

time = datetime.timedelta(seconds=x) # converse value "x" seconds to time (h,m,s)
print("All running time will gonna take",time,"seconds") # total time spent running
start_time = datetime.time(6,52,0) # time from where he started running
print("The running started in",start_time)
end_time = (start_time + time) # time when he ended running
print(end_time)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add delta to python datetime.time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448592/how-to-add-delta-to-python-datetime-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only add the timedelta to a `datetime.datetime` object, not a `datetime.time` object (probably in order to avoid overflows).

So simple fix, use `start_time = datetime.datetime(2021, 04, 21, 6,52,0)`

Comment: It's been solved, thank you very much! Well there is a lot to learn, first week into python :)

Comment: Good luck with your python journey!  (and because you're new: don't forget to mark one of the answers as accepted/upvote so that it is marked as answered :) )

Answer (score 0):

Please find below answer .check if it what you desired.May be you can check [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448592/how-to-add-delta-to-python-datetime-time) answer

```
import datetime
# first run, 1 mile

pace_minutes1 = 8
pace_seconds1 = 15
distance = 1  #1 mile
b = ((pace_minutes1 * 60) + pace_seconds1) * distance
print(b)

# second run, 3 mile
pace_minutes2 = 7
pace_seconds2 = 12
distance = 3  # 3 miles
a = ((pace_minutes2 * 60) + pace_seconds2) * distance
print(a)

# third run, 1 mile run
pace_minutes3 = 8
pace_seconds3 = 15
distance = 1 # 1 mile
c = ((pace_minutes3 * 60) + pace_seconds3) * distance
print(c)

x = (a + b + c)
print(x, "seconds")

time = datetime.timedelta(seconds=x) # converse value "x" seconds to time (h,m,s)
print("All running time will gonna take",time,"seconds") # total time spent running
start_time = datetime.time(6,52,0) # time from where he started running
# print(type(start_time))
# print(type(time))
print("The running started in",start_time)
end_time = (dt.datetime.combine(dt.date(1,1,1),start_time) + time).time()
print(end_time)
```