# Calculating end-time from user given start-time and minutes in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate and store an end-time (formatted as hh:mm:ss) in my database given a user input start-time (formatted as hh:mm) that I add 'x' minutes to.

What tools does Python offer to help with this?

EDIT: Sorry I hastily posted this question. Allow me to add more specifics!

I need to parse an input time given by the user. I use Flask WTForms to have the user input a start time in the format "hh:mm"

I then want to take that form data, add 'x' minutes to it, and store it in my database as a TIME field, which is formatted as "hh:mm:ss".

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448592/how-to-add-delta-to-python-datetime-time) help you?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `datetime` module.

```
import datetime
start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime('11:23', '%H:%M') # parse time
end_time = start_time + datetime.timedelta(minutes = 5) # add minutes
print(datetime.datetime.strftime(end_time, '%H:%M:%S')) # format and print
# 11:28:00
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be a simple example of a highly recommended tool ([pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org)), it allows you to handle instances of `datetime` and **methods** to insert `SQL` data into your database.

```
>>> user_starts  # user starts input
array([[36506],      [33486],      [25414],      [33987],
       [37577],      [ 4320],      [40926],      [24995],
       [13390],      [36733],      [19153],      [29232],
       [30907],      [13180],      [21200],      [23616],
       [ 4033],      [ 9284],      [31117],      [18431]])
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(user_starts, colums=['id']) 
>>> df['Time'] = pd.date_range(start='11/30/2021', periods=len(user_starts), freq='H')
>>> df.head()
       id                Time
0   36506 2021-11-30 00:00:00
1   33486 2021-11-30 01:00:00
2   25414 2021-11-30 02:00:00
3   33987 2021-11-30 03:00:00
4   37577 2021-11-30 04:00:00
```

Write records stored in a DataFrame to a SQL database:
`sqlalchemy`

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
>>> engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=False)
>>> df.to_sql(['id', 'Time'], con=engine)
>>> engine.execute("SELECT * FROM users").fetchall()
```